Book of literary genres and character types?
Saw a writer interviewed once and he talked about having a well known reference book that delineates story genres and fundamental character types.
Unfortunately, I neglected to write down the title. Anyone know any well known books of this type? Or if there is one book that stands out among the rest?

Wikipedia has a relevant article, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_genres.

Some suggestions:
Vladimir Propp, Morphology of the Tale (1927)
Stith Thompson, Motif-Index of Folk-Literature (1932-58)
Hans-Jörg Uther, The Types of International Folktales: A Classification and Bibliography (1961)
See also: Aarne–Thompson–Uther Index

Those references are awesome (they come out of the Russian formalist area of literary criticism). In some sense TV tropes takes this to the limit for modern TV and movies (mostly English).
